# Why react useQuery() doesnt fetch the newest data after a mutation?

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

**I have a code like this**

```
const [inputComment, setInputComment] = useState('');

const [
  commentPost,
  { data: data4, loading: loading4, errorCreate4 },
] = useMutation(COMMENT_POST);

const { error: error2, loading: loading2, data: data2 } = useQuery(
  GET_POST_BY_ID,
  {
    variables: {
      postid: item.id,
    },
  },
);

const doComment = () => {
  commentPost({
    variables: {
      postId: item.id,
      userEmail: email,
      comment: inputComment,
    },
  })
    .then(({ data }) => {
      setInputComment('');
      console.log('success');
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log('not success');
    });
};
```

This is supposed to get the data, and when I do comment then it runs the mutation and re-render everything.

My problem is, it re-render alright BUT the data that the useQuery fetch is not the newest data a.k.a the data before I add a new comment.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem??

**Please help :(**

Comment: This useQuery it is from which library ? apollo or react-query ?

Comment: Can you also include your COMMENT_POST and GET_POST_BY_ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mutation modifies data on the **server side**.
Once your mutation is done, you should **refetch** your data in order to get the modified version in your local cache on the **client side**.

By guessing how your mutation and query actually work, here is how it would look like:

```
const [
  commentPost,
  { data: data4, loading: loading4, errorCreate4 },
] = useMutation(COMMENT_POST, {
  refetchQueries: [
    { query: GET_POST_BY_ID, variables: { postid: item.id } }
  ]
});
```

Otherwise, intead of refetching from the server, you could update the local cache directly.
More info can be found [here in the official documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#updating-local-data).

Answer (score 0):

I assume `commentPost` is an insert operation, not an update of a single record. In this case, Apollo useMutation will not update the cache for you. **You need to modify the cache yourself.** The [official Apollo documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#the-update-function) has covered this use case with an example. You may want to revise the usage of [writeFragment](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#writefragment) as well.

**Below are directly from apollo docs on cache update for list fields.**

> In most cases, a mutation response should include any object(s) the
> mutation modified. This enables Apollo Client to normalize those
> objects and cache them according to their __typename and id fields (by
> default).
>
> ...
>
> When a mutation's response is insufficient to update all modified
> fields in your cache (such as certain list fields), you can define an
> update function to apply manual changes to your cached data after a
> mutation.

```
const [addTodo] = useMutation(ADD_TODO, {
    update(cache, { data: { addTodo } }) {
      cache.modify({
        fields: {
          todos(existingTodos = []) {
            const newTodoRef = cache.writeFragment({
              data: addTodo,
              fragment: gql`
                fragment NewTodo on Todo {
                  id
                  type
                }
              `
            });
            return [...existingTodos, newTodoRef];
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

---

### **EDIT**

I noticed another answer suggests using **refetch**, which is not a bad option for starters. However, updating the cache is the recommended approach over refetch. You can refer to the Apollo blog article [When To Use Refetch Queries in Apollo Client](https://www.apollographql.com/blog/apollo-client/caching/when-to-use-refetch-queries/).

Below are some quotes you should note from this article.

> If you’re just getting started with GraphQL, I think the mental model of passing in the queries that you’d like to re-run after a mutation is an easy one to wrap your head around.
>
> ...
>
> The advantage here is that this approach is straightforward. The disadvantage is that we’re fetching the entire list of data again when we might not need to.
>
> ...
>
> For a more efficient use of bandwidth and network round-trips, we can rely on cache normalization and **update** functions.